# Is random homomorphism from free product of $k$ copies of $\mathbb Z_2$ to orthogonal group $O(3)$ injective?

Tags: group-theory, random-variables, orthogonal-matrices, reflection, free-product

Consider the group $G = \ast_{i=1}^k \mathbb Z_2 = \langle (g_i)_{i=1}^k : g_i^2 = 1 \rangle$. Suppose we define a homomorphism $\phi$ from $G$ to $O(3)$ by setting $\phi(g_i)$ to the reflection in a randomly chosen plane $H_i = \{x\in\mathbb R^3 : x\cdot \hat v_i = 0\}$, where the unit vectors $\hat v_i$ are iid and uniformly distributed over the sphere.

Can we show that $\phi$ is injective almost surely?

[Someone else has written some code (for a programming competition) that relies on that assumption](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/70358?#comment-548508), but they did not describe a proof, and while the assumption seems intuitively obvious to me, I have been unable to produce a formal proof.

I'm also curious whether this is true in $O(2)$ or in higher dimensions.

[edit: It's false for $O(2)$ when $k > 2$. The identities at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_and_reflections_in_two_dimensions imply any such $\phi$ will have $(g_1g_2g_3)^2$ in the kernel regardless of $\hat v_1,\hat v_2,\hat v_3$.]

Comment: It can't be true in $O(2)$ (take determinants).

Comment: Do you have a reference for "injective almost surely"?  It is certainly true that the composition of a sequence of iid uniform reflections equals the identity with probability zero, if that's all you mean, in any dimension greater than $1$

Comment: I just mean the probability of not being injective (nontrivial kernel) is 0. As Qiaochu points out, it's false in dimension 2. I'm actually not sure how taking determinants tells you that (maybe he can clarify @QiaochuYuan), but I've added an example at the end of the question.

Comment: Any group $G$ that embeds in $O(2)$ has a subgroup of index at most $2$ that embeds in $SO(2)$ (by taking determinants), and so is in particular abelian.

Comment: Yes, it is: There exists a countable union of algebraic subsets of positive codimension in $Hom(G, O(3))$ such that away from these subsets, the homomorphisms are injective. Same for $O(n)$, $n>3$.

Comment: Defining these subsets is easy, for each $w\in G-\{1\}$ take $A_w=\{r: G\to O(3)| r(w)=1\}$. The difficult part is proving that each $A_w$ has positive codimension. This is usually done via Galois conjugation to a faithful representation to $O(2,1)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan for someone who knows hardly any Lie theory, algebraic geometry, representation theory, or really anything beyond undergraduate algebra, analysis, and topology, do you have any references that would help me to understand and flesh out your argument?

Comment: I was already familiar with the definition of a faithful representation; I hadn't seen the indefinite orthogonal group before but the definition was easy; I'm not sure how "algebraic set" is being used here but the definition of $A_w$ looks analogous to the definition of a variety in algebraic geometry (I'd seen that a few times but never seriously learned any AG); and I've only heard of "Galois conjugates" in the context of elementary Galois theory (which I've mostly forgotten but could prob relearn quickly). I'm not sure how the last applies to this context.

Comment: Though I'm seeing some hits for Galois conjugation + faithful representation in MathOverflow and GBooks, which might be enough for me to figure it out.

Comment: And ofc when I wrote "for someone who ..." I was speaking of myself not you. Not very clear on my part. Woops.

Comment: @dysonsfrog: I will try to find a reference but you may have tough time understanding these due to limited background. Proofs are a bit similar to ones for homomorphisms of free groups, see for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492799/there-is-a-free-group-f-2-in-so3. I will add a detailed answer when I have more time.